# Storing session data in eclipse rcp application

Tags: eclipse-rcp

Is using `IPreferenceStore` the right way to store few frequently accessed java objects used to paint the views? I want something like an "Custom application cache" for my RCP application

Answer (score 3):

`IPreferenceStore` is for storing preferences! Normally you would only store things here that are going to appear on a preference page - although there is nothing to enforce this.

For more general storage use `Platform.getStateLocation(bundle)` to get the location in the workspace `.metadata` where your plugin can store any information it wishes:

```java
Bundle bundle = Platform.getBundle("your-plugin-id");

IPath stateLocPath = Platform.getStateLocation(bundle);
```

`stateLocPath` will be a directory (usually `workspace-path/.metadata/.plugins/your-plugin-id`). It is up to your plugin to manage the files stored in this directory.

If you don't need the objects to be persisted across sessions that you can just use a normal Java structure such as a list or map as a field in your plug-in `Activator`.

Comment: thanks for stepping in answer my question. Could you elaborate more on this for my clear understanding?

Comment: doing this way I am assuming that I need to use files to store and retrieve data. But does the APIs related to IPath support storing and retrieval of key-value pairs? A quick search returned `LinkedHashMap` as a light-weight in-memory cache. But would this be accessible across Perspevtive switches ?